# Convert all images on S3 to webp format

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, webp

I need to convert all my wordpress images hosted on S3 to webp format. I need to figure out some way to do it without breaking my site. If I download all the images and convert them to webp and reupload them on S3, will that work or will it break my site because it will be looking for png format and the images will be served in webp format?

Comment: You might receive a better response at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/